# Angular: intercept HTTP errors and continue chain

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to treat certain HTTP error codes as non-errors, and handle their responses normally. So I tried adding an `HttpInterceptor` to catch 500 status codes, and return the original response (which Angular puts in `error.error`):

```
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (error.status === 500) {
          return of(error.error);
        } else {
          return throwError('server error');
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

But then if there's an error, anything that I had piped to my http request doesn't get executed. For example, if I do this, the log statement doesn't happen:

```
this.http.get(...).pipe(
  tap(console.log)
)
```

How can I make this work?

Here's a [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/call-http-request-in-angular-6-kuuuof)...it never logs "got result" from AppComponent.

Comment: You can use `tap({ next: console.log, error: console.log })` if you want to log also errors.

Comment: you're saying in the case of the 500 response, the tap isn't executing? or in non 500 responses? or both? I'd expect tap to get skipped in the case of non 500 errors, but should execute in the 500 case

Comment: @bryan60 Right, it’s not executing even for 500 errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your chain stops working since Angular http module [filters](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/698b0288bee60b8c5926148b79b5b93f454098db/packages/common/http/src/client.ts#L510) messages that it  receives from interceptor:

```
const res$: Observable<HttpResponse<any>> = <Observable<HttpResponse<any>>>events$.pipe(
        filter((event: HttpEvent<any>) => event instanceof HttpResponse));
```

As you can see you should return stream of `HttpResponse` class like:

```
import { HttpResponse, ... } from '@angular/common/http';
...

if (error.status === 404) {
  console.log('caught', error.error);

  return of(new HttpResponse({
    body: error.error
  }));
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/call-http-request-in-angular-6-fx9sxj?file=src%2Fapp%2Ferror-interceptor.ts)**

Comment: Oh my god....I could have spent a week on this and never figured that out. Thank you!

Comment: Consider to return just `new HttpResponse({ body: error.error })` (not the observable). Error handler within the http interceptor should return an error or response object.

Comment: To clarify my point, you can use the 'of' method to make a observable, but if your error handler function defined with an async keyword, use return with a plain object.